# Write multiple files to excel using pandas &excelwriter

Tags: pandas, loops, for-loop, export-to-excel

## The list of dataframes

df_list = [summary, df3, df4, df5, df6]

## Names of excel sheets where the output has to be written

Names = ['Liability','Expenses','Income','Asset']

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"E:\GL\2040001.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

## If a dataframe has output then the file has to be written to excel

for i in df_list:
if i.empty is False:
for j in Names:
i.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = j)

I want the files which are not empty to be written with its corresponding dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if the dataframe is empty. If it is, you do nothing. If it is not, you write to Excel:

```
df_list = [summary, df3, df4, df5, df6]
names = ['Liability','Expenses','Income','Asset']
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"E:\GL\2040001.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
for df, name in zip(df_list, names):
    if not df.is_empty:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = name)
```

Note that variable names in Python are preferred to be lowercase. Also, try not to use absolute path but use relative ones.

Comment: Can you pls explain what is wrong with my code:                                                                                                df_list = [summary, df3, df4, df5, df6]
Names = ['Liability','Expenses','Income','Asset']
for i in df_list:
    if i.empty is False:                                                                                                            
       for j in Names:
            i.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = j)

Comment: It is not easy to tell because your code is not well formatted, but it seems that the inner cycle is wrong: as I got it, you do not want to write each dataframe to all the sheets you have.